# Neither the property "password" nor one of the methods exists in twig/symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I want to make reuse of the form field by passing `show_password_field` as true  in the optional value in `AddUserType.php`. My edit form field should not contain password field. So I have used this

```
if ($options['show_password_field']) {
      $builder->add('password','password',array('required'=>true));
    }
```

in form type. Can anybody figure it out? What is the problem in line 37 of twig file.

> Neither the property "password" nor one of the methods "password()",
>   "getpassword()"/"ispassword()" or "__call()" exist and have public
>   access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" in
>   SokosimuEditorBundle:User:addUser.html.twig at line 37.

**AddUserType.php**

```
   namespace Sokosimu\EditorBundle\Form\Type;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
   use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

  class AddUserType extends AbstractType
  {

 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
    $builder->add('alias','text',array('required'=>false));
    $builder->add('email', 'email',array('required'=>false));

    if ($options['show_password_field']) {
        $builder->add('password','password',array('required'=>true));
    }

    $builder->add('mobile','text',array('required'=>false));
    $builder->add('submit', 'submit');
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Sokosimu\UserBundle\Entity\User',
        'show_password_field' => true
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the name of this type.
 *
 * @return string The name of this type
 */
 public function getName()
 {
     return 'adduser';
  }
}
```

And line 37 in addUser.html.twig

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="password">Password:</label>
   {{ form_widget(form.password,{'attr':{'class':'form-row'}}) }}
   {{ form_errors(form.password) }}
  </div>
```

**Controller that renders edit**

```
public function editEditorUserAction(User $user,Request $request){

    $form = $this->createForm(new AddUserType(),$user,array(
        'show_password_field' => false));

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form ->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()){
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $editUser = $user ->getEditoruser();

        $em->persist($editUser);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sokosimu_editor_userlist'));
    }

    return $this->render('SokosimuEditorBundle:User:addUser.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
         'user' => $user->getId()
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must check if form.password exists.

```
{% if form.password is defined %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        {{ form_widget(form.password,{'attr':{'class':'form-row'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.password) }}
    </div> 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer panche14.

Comment: For those who get that error and are using camel case, you can also check if you did not write in the twig with snake case. For example form_widget(child.admin_note) instead of form_widget(child.adminNote) - that is super hard to notice even when it writes in the error message admin_note